# Graficar 2 arreglos en un widget

Tags: python, pyqt5, matplotlib, python-3.7, pyqt

Estoy tratando de graficar dos arreglos con matplotlib utilizando PyQt5, el problema de nuevo es que al correr el programa y doy click en el boton graficar se cierra. Declare un widget en Qt Designer para poder mostrar la grafica.

Este es el codigo, primero declaro el widget y le doy la orden de graficar los arreglos x y sx que anteriormente son calculados, no se si tenga que declara alguna libreria extra como QWidget o algo asi para que pueda mostrar la grafica de estos 2 arreglos.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIntValidator, QDoubleValidator
from PyQt5.QtCore import QLocale
import math
import matplotlib

#Clase Heredada de QMainWindow (Constructor de ventana)
class Ventana(QMainWindow):
      #Metodo constructor de la clase
      def __init__(self):
            #Iniciar el objeto QMainWindow
            QMainWindow.__init__(self)
            #Cargar la Configuracion del archivo ui en el objeto
            uic.loadUi("Bocinas.ui",self)
            self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.Guardar)
            #Convierte los valores en float e int
            self._int_validator = QIntValidator()
            self._float_validator = QDoubleValidator()
            self.lineEdit.setValidator(self._float_validator)
            self.lineEdit_2.setValidator(self._int_validator)
            self.lineEdit_3.setValidator(self._float_validator)
            self.lineEdit_4.setValidator(self._float_validator)
            self.lineEdit_5.setValidator(self._float_validator)
            #Pone los lineEdit en 0 predeterminado
            self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("0")
            self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText("0")
            self.lineEdit_3.setPlaceholderText("0")
            self.lineEdit_4.setPlaceholderText("0")
            self.lineEdit_5.setPlaceholderText("0")
            self._locale = QLocale()




      def closeEvent(self,event):
            resultado = QMessageBox.question(self,"Salir..","¿Seguro quiere salir?",QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No)
            if resultado == QMessageBox.Yes:
                  event.accept()
            else:
                  event.ignore()

      def Guardar(self):
            st, _ = self._locale.toDouble(self.lineEdit.text())
            l, _ = self._locale.toInt(self.lineEdit_2.text())
            xo, _ = self._locale.toDouble(self.lineEdit_3.text())
            m, _ = self._locale.toDouble(self.lineEdit_4.text())
            M, _ = self._locale.toDouble(self.lineEdit_5.text())
            sx=[]
            x=[]
            if self.radioButton.isChecked():
                  ls=l+1
                  for i in range(ls):
                        s=st*((i/xo)**2)
                        sx.append(s)
                        x.append(i)
            elif self.radioButton_2.isChecked():
                  ls=l+1
                  for i in range(ls):
                        s=st*(math.cosh((m*i)/2)**2)
                        sx.append(s)
                        x.append(i)
            elif self.radioButton_3.isChecked():
                  ls=l+1
                  for i in range(ls):
                        s=st*((math.cosh((m*i)/2))+(M*math.sinh(m*i)/2)**2)
                        sx.append(s)
                        x.append(i)
            elif self.radioButton_4.isChecked():
                  ls=l+1
                  for i in range(ls):
                        s=st*math.exp(m*i)
                        sx.append(s)
                        x.append(i)
            else:
                  QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Advertencia', "Seleccione algun tipo de Bocina",QMessageBox.Retry)

            self.widget.canvas.axes.plot(x,sx)
            self.widget.canvas.axes.legend("Estilo de Bocina",loc="upper right")
            self.widget.canvas.axes.set_title("Bocina")
            self.widget.canvas.draw()

#Instancia para iniciar una app
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
#Crear un objeto de la clase
_ventana = Ventana()
#Mostrar ventana
_ventana.show()
#Ejecutar app
app.exec_()
```

Este es el codigo extraido de Qt designer por si alguna duda extra

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file 'Bocinas.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.14.1
#
# WARNING! All changes made in this file will be lost!


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(800, 600)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(560, 140, 191, 51))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 100, 273, 153))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.layoutWidget.setFont(font)
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.verticalLayout.setContentsMargins(3, 1, 0, 10)
        self.verticalLayout.setSpacing(4)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_2.setFont(font)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_2)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_3.setFont(font)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_3)
        self.label_4 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_4.setFont(font)
        self.label_4.setObjectName("label_4")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_4)
        self.label_5 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(14)
        self.label_5.setFont(font)
        self.label_5.setObjectName("label_5")
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.label_5)
        self.radioButton = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 340, 171, 21))
        self.radioButton.setObjectName("radioButton")
        self.radioButton_2 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 370, 171, 21))
        self.radioButton_2.setObjectName("radioButton_2")
        self.radioButton_3 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 400, 171, 21))
        self.radioButton_3.setObjectName("radioButton_3")
        self.radioButton_4 = QtWidgets.QRadioButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.radioButton_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(410, 430, 171, 21))
        self.radioButton_4.setObjectName("radioButton_4")
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 100, 161, 21))
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 130, 161, 21))
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 160, 161, 21))
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.lineEdit_4 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_4.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 190, 161, 21))
        self.lineEdit_4.setObjectName("lineEdit_4")
        self.lineEdit_5 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.centralwidget)
        self.lineEdit_5.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(380, 220, 161, 21))
        self.lineEdit_5.setObjectName("lineEdit_5")
        self.widget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.widget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(70, 280, 311, 231))
        self.widget.setObjectName("widget")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 800, 22))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menuArchivo = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menuArchivo.setObjectName("menuArchivo")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.actionAbrir = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionAbrir.setObjectName("actionAbrir")
        self.actionGuardar = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionGuardar.setObjectName("actionGuardar")
        self.menuArchivo.addAction(self.actionAbrir)
        self.menuArchivo.addAction(self.actionGuardar)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menuArchivo.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Graficar"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Área de garganta"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Longitud"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Distancia entre origen y garganta"))
        self.label_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Ensanchamiento"))
        self.label_5.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Factor de forma"))
        self.radioButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Conica"))
        self.radioButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Catenoidal"))
        self.radioButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Hiperbolica"))
        self.radioButton_4.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Exponencial"))
        self.menuArchivo.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "Archivo"))
        self.actionAbrir.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Abrir"))
        self.actionGuardar.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Guardar"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Primero de todo `canvas` no es un atributo de `self.widget`, instancia de `QWidget`.

Para mostrar gráficos de Matplotlib, dicha biblioteca dispone de backends propios para distintos frameworks gráficos, en el caso de Qt debes usar [`matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg.FigureCanvasQTAgg`](https://matplotlib.org/api/backend_qt5agg_api.html)

```
import math
import sys

import matplotlib
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt5agg import FigureCanvasQTAgg
from matplotlib.backends.backend_qt4agg import NavigationToolbar2QT
from matplotlib.figure import Figure

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QMessageBox, QVBoxLayout
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIntValidator, QDoubleValidator
from PyQt5.QtCore import QLocale


# Clase Heredada de QMainWindow (Constructor de ventana)
class Ventana(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
      # Metodo constructor de la clase
      def __init__(self):
            # LLamar al constructor del padre QMainWindow
            super().__init__()
            # Cargar la Configuracion del archivo ui en el objeto
            uic.loadUi("Bocinas.ui", self)
            self.pushButton.clicked.connect(self.guardar)
            # Convierte los valores en float e int
            self._int_validator = QIntValidator()
            self._float_validator = QDoubleValidator()
            self.lineEdit.setValidator(self._float_validator)
            self.lineEdit_2.setValidator(self._int_validator)
            self.lineEdit_3.setValidator(self._float_validator)
            self.lineEdit_4.setValidator(self._float_validator)
            self.lineEdit_5.setValidator(self._float_validator)
            # Pone los lineEdit en 0 predeterminado
            self.lineEdit.setPlaceholderText("0")
            self.lineEdit_2.setPlaceholderText("0")
            self.lineEdit_3.setPlaceholderText("0")
            self.lineEdit_4.setPlaceholderText("0")
            self.lineEdit_5.setPlaceholderText("0")
            self._locale = QLocale()

            self.figure = Figure()
            self.canvas = FigureCanvasQTAgg(self.figure)
            self.toolbar = NavigationToolbar2QT(self.canvas, self.widget)
            self.axes = self.figure.add_subplot(111)
            self.plot_layout = QVBoxLayout()
            self.plot_layout.addWidget(self.toolbar)
            self.plot_layout.addWidget(self.canvas)
            self.widget.setLayout(self.plot_layout)

      def closeEvent(self,event):
            resultado = QMessageBox.question(
                self, "Salir..", "¿Seguro quiere salir?",
                QMessageBox.Yes | QMessageBox.No
                )
            if resultado == QMessageBox.Yes:
                  event.accept()
            else:
                  event.ignore()

      def guardar(self):
            st, _ = self._locale.toDouble(self.lineEdit.text())
            l, _ = self._locale.toInt(self.lineEdit_2.text())
            xo, _ = self._locale.toDouble(self.lineEdit_3.text())
            m, _ = self._locale.toDouble(self.lineEdit_4.text())
            M, _ = self._locale.toDouble(self.lineEdit_5.text())
            sx = []
            x = []
            if self.radioButton.isChecked():
                  ls=l+1
                  for i in range(ls):
                        s=st*((i/xo)**2)
                        sx.append(s)
                        x.append(i)
            elif self.radioButton_2.isChecked():
                  ls=l+1
                  for i in range(ls):
                        s=st*(math.cosh((m*i)/2)**2)
                        sx.append(s)
                        x.append(i)
            elif self.radioButton_3.isChecked():
                  ls=l+1
                  for i in range(ls):
                        s=st*((math.cosh((m*i)/2))+(M*math.sinh(m*i)/2)**2)
                        sx.append(s)
                        x.append(i)
            elif self.radioButton_4.isChecked():
                  ls=l+1
                  for i in range(ls):
                        s=st*math.exp(m*i)
                        sx.append(s)
                        x.append(i)
            else:
                  QMessageBox.warning(self, 'Advertencia', "Seleccione algun tipo de Bocina",QMessageBox.Retry)

            self.axes.clear()
            self.axes.plot(x, sx)
            self.axes.legend("Estilo de Bocina",loc="upper right")
            self.axes.set_title("Bocina")
            self.axes.plot(x, sx)
            self.canvas.draw()


#Instancia para iniciar una app
app = QApplication(sys.argv)
#Crear un objeto de la clase
_ventana = Ventana()
#Mostrar ventana
_ventana.show()
#Ejecutar app
app.exec_()
```